# Conditions for Penalized Logistic Regression (Epidemiology)

Tags: regression, logistic, optimization, regularization

Is penalized logistic regression only appropriate when the likelihood of the outcome is very low, or when the number of variables exceeds the number of observations?

Wondering if it can be a tool to use generally in order to shrink variables that "contribute" less to the observed effect in epidemiology.